# cumulative standard normal distribution formula

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I need to calculate a P-value (for significance checking) out of the Z value, mean(0), standarddeviation(1), normal distrubution being cummulative.

Is there a function in PHP that could do that?

This is my current code:

```
$P_value = (1/sqrt(2*pi()))*exp(-0.5*pow($this->ZValue,2));
```

ZValue = -4,688072309 which is confirmed the right value.

Expected value: 1,37895E-06

Value: 6.9681241978373E-6

used formula:

```
\phi (x)={\frac  {1}{{\sqrt  {2\pi }}}}\,e^{{-{\frac  12}x^{2}}}
```

I am searching for the cumulative standard normal distribution formula so I can insert it in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example in c++ of an implementation. Let me know if it helps. If not I will remove the answer :).

[image: Method for computing the cumulative distribution]

Comment: Thanks, there are a few things unclear though. How did you get those a's? How did you get the value 0.2316419 for k? Where did you define the Z value?

Comment: It is a pretty standard algorithm (not my own formulation) I will dig out a reference for this.

Comment: I was compute derivative pricing from Espen Haug book, but there is a more accurate approximation (though the above was ok for my case) [this is the more accurate version](https://lyle.smu.edu/~aleskovs/emis/sqc2/accuratecumnorm.pdf) .

Comment: @Chinny84 I implemented the code, but it doesn't give the expected value for the values where Z is under 0. Any ideas?

Comment: @tootone cheers for that. I will try it now.

Comment: Does it not? Send me a copy of the code and I can have a look. This code was implemented from the source I provided above.

Comment: @TooTone I have tried to put the preamble to format my code (admittedly python code), but it doesn't seem to work. Cheers

Comment: @Ajaxkevi I implemented it in python and I got agreement with the table results :/.

Comment: @Chinny84, got it working now. The Z in K had to be adjusted as well.

Comment: @Chinny84 yes you're right, it seems  "<!-- language-all: c++ -->" is stackoverflow specific. Sorry about that. You can still get the monospaced font by indenting by 4 spaces, but no syntax highlighting.

Comment: @tootone I will play around with it. I know in latex the packages to allow programming syntax, but this site seems to have a hybrid.

Comment: So you had to vary the k formulation? I did not have to do that myself. But as long as you got it working that is the important thing. Though, the above works for cases that I have checked, it might be worth while checking the other link I gave and implement that if it's production code you are working on.